# File not being uploaded using minIO's putObject?

Tags: java, minio

I am using Minio's JAVA SDK. Is there a way to copy the objects from one Minio server to other?

I tried:

```
InputStream inputStream = minioClientServer1.getObject(getBucket(), fileName);
minioClientServer2.putObject(getBucket(), fileName, inputStream, (long) inputStream.available(), null, null, contentType);
```

When I try, I get

```
java.net.ProtocolException: expected * bytes but received *
```

Is there a way to resolve this?